# Input and Output Argument(s)/Parameter(s) of GetDefaultLayout function from input.dll

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-layout

[image: GetDefaultLayout in DLL Export Viewer]
Please help me get the list of Arguments/Parameters to `GetDefaultLayout` function from *C:\Windows\System32\input.dll*.
**This function is about keyboard layouts. And I already know how to get default keyboard layout. I just want to know the parameters for GetDefaultLayout function in input.dll.**

*For use in Excel VBA but info in any language is appreciated.*
Searched all over the internet, no information found.
Another similar undocumented function: `GetLayoutDescription` in the same dll was mentioned [cyberforum](https://www.cyberforum.ru/post15119827.html) & [vbforums](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?889679-How-to-get-the-input-method-name-on-win10-computer) (both from 2020) and [miloush](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/09/29/8968315.html) (from 2010).

Checked exported functions from *input.dll* using Dll Export Viewer, PE Explorer etc. and found that function listed but no [documentation on MS site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tsf/enumenabledlayoutortip), unlike other functions, in the same DLL, such as: `EnumEnabledLayoutOrTip`.

`EnumEnabledLayoutOrTip` and `GetLayoutDescription` were successfully called by using a combination of `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` & `DispCallFunc` using **CC_STDCALL** and **CC_CDECL** calling conventions respectively, with [Jaafar Triback's help](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/load-a-custom-dll-programmatically-from-another-path.1102770/page-2#post-5813936). The arguments were mentioned in the [link above](https://www.cyberforum.ru/post15119827.html). If that could be done, this function should be call-able!

I know that there are other functions like `GetKeyboardLayout` or `GetKeyboardLayoutName` or `GetKeyboardLayoutList` win32 API functions and also know that the same information can be obtained from the Registry, in fact, I know that all these functions retrieve information from the registry. I already knew how to get the keyboard layout information.[image: KeyboardLayoutInfo in VBA]

The goal of this question is not to get the Default keyboard layout information but to be able to call a function whose arguments/parameters were left unexplained by MS.
I understand that it's been like this for a reason but I am not trying to reverse-engineer it or doing this for profit but to educate myself how to do this and to help others like me.

Disassembling the code can yield the function arguments/parameters but at my current knowledge level, that's too hard.
I was told that arguments/parameters of a function can be viewed in Visual Studio and Ollydbg or IDA etc. but both `GetLayoutDescription` and `GetDefaultLayout` do not show such information even with undecorate option.

I tried to call it like `GetDefaultLayout(StrPtr(sBuffer),uBufLength)` or tried both ANSI or Unicode string passing etc. and even tried passing just a `0&` but still it crashes my Excel file so many times damaging my .xlsm file so much so that I can't even copy/paste into it and currently doing a chkdsk operation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you had a look at the [SystemParametersInfoA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) API call? Or [GetProcessDefaultLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getprocessdefaultlayout).

Comment: @HelO'Ween, many thanks for sharing info. SystemParametersInfoA is very interesting. A lot of useful stuff there. GetProcessDefaultLayout, according to your link, is for: "The layout specifies how text and graphics are laid out in a window; the default is left to right." Sorry that I failed to explain clearly. What I meant with layout is the keyboard layout. But I also mentioned that I wanted to find out how to call the undocumented function primarily. It is not about the actual keyboard layout anymore because I got it already. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Nah, I understood what you're after in the OP already, just that _I_ derped the answer with linking GetProcessDefaultLayout. I obviously hallucinated "keyboard layout" somewhere in that link. My bad, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @HelO'Ween, no worries. You didn't waste my time. I learned new stuff from the SystemParametersInfoA. I even got to know how to determine current keyboard layout change method with SPI_GETTHREADLOCALINPUTSETTINGS. You did help me out! And many thanks for that. Have a nice day, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `WINAPI HRESULT GetDefaultLayout(LPCWSTR pszUserReg, LPWSTR pszLayout, LPUINT uBufLength);`

Usage seems straightforward:

```cpp
std::wstring GetDefaultLayoutProfileId()
{
    typedef HRESULT(WINAPI* GetDefaultLayoutFunc)(LPCWSTR pszUserReg, LPWSTR pszLayout, LPUINT uBufLength);
    static GetDefaultLayoutFunc GetDefaultLayout = reinterpret_cast<GetDefaultLayoutFunc>(::GetProcAddress(::LoadLibraryA("input.dll"), "GetDefaultLayout"));

    if (!GetDefaultLayout)
        return {};

    UINT length = 0;

    CHECK(SUCCEEDED(GetDefaultLayout(nullptr, nullptr, &length)));

    std::wstring defaultLayoutProfileId;
    defaultLayoutProfileId.resize(length);

    CHECK(SUCCEEDED(GetDefaultLayout(nullptr, defaultLayoutProfileId.data(), &length)));

    return defaultLayoutProfileId;
}

...

// Returns default layout profile set in user settings (with IME support!)
// For example "0409:00000409" for English - US layout
std::wstring defaultLayoutProfileId = GetDefaultLayoutProfileId();
```

string format of the layout is:

> <LangID>:<KLID>

The string format of the text service profile (TSF IME) is:

> <LangID>:{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tsf/installlayoutortip#remarks).

Comment: Thanks for your kind interest. I already knew how to call GetLayoutDescription. I've also read those sites you referenced as well. If you read carefully, you will find that I asked for ***GetDefaultLayout*** function, for which, I also already knew how to, some months ago. Just busy with other stuff to update this question.

Comment: @NayLynn Sorry, missed question a bit. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yep, this time, you got it right. I'll accept your answer & mark my question as answered. How I found it out myself was, I had to use DispCallFunc blindly & tested different variables. I found that the first parameter has to be 0& in VBA (may be a null in other languages) or else crash. Anyway, if you don't mind, could you please tell me how I can access information like that? I even tried to use OllyDbg, but I don't really understand how it works. So, I had to blindly test and crashed Excel in VBA like 50 times, until I got it right. This is a very useful function.

Comment: I have used Ghidra tool to open input.dll, then downloaded PDB with "File->Download PDB file..." function and decompiled GetDefaultLayout method. In result I received code and just analized it with my eyes: https://gist.github.com/DJm00n/2ff4604f13d294a6fbd5113a89676e4a Just try it yourself. Good luck!

Comment: First param is used to provide the registry path of the user. Same as in documented  EnumEnabledLayoutOrTip() function. If null (zero) is provided - then HKEY_CURRENT_USER (or 0x80000001 hex) is used.

Comment: Thank you again, for the explanation and the tool and for the first param. You've taught me how to fish. I appreciate it.